# Finding a float number in a range

Tags: python, typeerror

I am checking conditions of time range from a csv file. There are around 20,000 rows of file and I would like to check if a given time is between start and end time. The csv contains columns such as time_check, time_window_start and time_window_end with time given as float values. It looks something like below:

| time_check | time_window_start | time_window_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.102 | 0.125 | 0.1320833 |

I tried following code but it doesn't work with float values :

```
df1 = df1[(time_check > time_window_start & time_check < time_window_end)]
```

It throws an error i.e. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'
How can I fix this typeError?

Comment: Parentheses.  `&` binds tighter than `>` and `<`.  Add the correct parentheses and this will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to this

```
df1 = df1[((df1.time_check > df1.time_window_start) & (df1.time_check < df1.time_window_end))]
```